# Android layout folders

Tags: java, android, layout, screen-resolution

Hi I'm developing an android application and I'm having trouble with the layout on nexus phones and tablets as they are very high resolution. I don't know which layout folder would be applicable to best match nexus 5, nexus 7, etc as they both have different screen sizes but very similar resolution. Can anyone give opinion to achieve this? I know probably I'll be needing different folders for the different phones (nexus 5 and nexus 7 to name a couple) but can't figure out the best ones to use. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some numbers for typical screen widths:

**320dp**: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).

**480dp**: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).

**600dp**: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).

**720dp**: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

Refer [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

And also:

For **nexus 7**

```
layout-large-hdpi
```

For **nexus 10**

```
layout-xlarge-xhdpi
```

Comment: what about nexus 5? would it be layout-hdpi?

Comment: I'm not sure, think layout-sw480dp for Nexaus 5

Comment: brilliant I'll give it a go now and let you know the results:) Thanks for the help

Comment: So I've found out that for a nexus 5 it uses the screen size configuration SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL, and Density configuration DENSITY_XXHIGH. I assume it would be layout-normal-xxhdpi? Also in accordance to images, would I have to have an image the size of the width of the device?

Comment: @Lokesh Nexaus 5 belongs to layout-sw320dp

Comment: According to the default Nexus 5 emulator, you can almost specifically target Nexus 5's specs using the "sw384dp-xxhdpi" folder name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use folder : layout-normal-land for landscape and layout-normal-port for portrait.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Its all [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), if you just read the whole article it'll fixe your problem, ive been dealing with this before and this article helped me. Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the sizes on this diagram are still much smaller than the resolution of the nexus devices. the resolution of the nexus 5 is 1080 x 1920 pixels, 4.95 inches (~445 ppi pixel density). So does this mean that it has a dpi of 445?

Comment: i think you dont need to worry about the resolution of the screen, you should focus on what screen sizes were your devices are. Or maybe Use a much higher resolution images and put in the device's respective folder e.g. if the device is 4.95in it should be on drawable-hdpi folder.

Comment: So how does the resolution work then if the resolution is 1080 x 1920 pixels, what would be the equivalent in dpi? Does it take screen size into accordance as well?

Comment: @Paddy1990 445ppi is xxhd if you take width 1080px and if you divide by 3 you will get 360dp that is smaller width of Nexus5. Method is following: you first find out ppi and find their category (ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi). size = mdpi = ldpi/0.75 = hdpi/1.5 = xhdpi/2 = xxhdpi/3